# Leading zeros of a binary number doesn't get printed

Tags: c++, binary, numbers

I am writing a code which involves converting a decimal number to binary and store the binary number. I'm not able to store the leading zeros in some of the binary number e.g 001101011 and instead it prints and stores -> 1101011. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: I`m using my mind reading powers and sense...missing code on your question...please post some code.

Comment: Well, if *you* are writing the code that performs the conversion, then it is *your* responsibility to add as many padding zeros in front as you need. If you already wrote the code that is supposed to add those zeros, but it doesn't work for some reason, then your code must contain a bug. We can't help you to find it without seeing the code. I can't speak for everyone, but my telepathy has very limited range.

Comment: An integer variable (e.g., `int`) holds a **value**. When you **display** a value you need to decide how to **represent** it. That's when you think about decimal versus binary versus hexadecimal, precision, leading zeros, etc. The **values** represented by `001101011` and `1101011` are the same; that value could also be displayed as `0x6B`, `0x006B`, `107`, `000000107`, etc., depending on how you decide to format it. But the formatting is part of **displaying** the value, not part of the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

With my mind reading powers I'm deducing that this will help you.

```
printf("%08x", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no standard data type for binary numbers in c++. So i guess you are using integers to store the binary number. So to print the leading zeroes just use this .

std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << binary_number << std::endl;

See http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/114864/setw-and-setfill.